# importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for pyproj

Tags: python, exe, pyproj

I wrote a code using the pyproj library and converted this code to an exe file for use on another computer. I added the pyproj to the requirements.txt file. And I installed the library with the requirements.txt file on the other computer I will use. When I run the exe file, I get the following error:

```
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for pyproj
```

I'd be glad if you can help.

Comment: Is there a way to tell which python executable installed the code and which one is running the code in the executable?

Comment: I solved the problem when I created the exe file with the command "pyinstaller --onefile --copy-metadata pyproj example.py". Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution for those who have problems like above while running the exe file:

```
 pyinstaller --onefile --copy-metadata pyproj "example.py"
```

For now this seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a change on pyproj when they updated to version 3.4.0

https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/1155

It now requires that the dist-info of the pyproj to be present, so it can find the "version" property inside the METADATA file, so if you have an slim installation (an installation without the dist-info folder) the project will break during the first run of its `pyproj/__init__.py`.

Another way to fix this problem would be to manually remove that line of the code, (line 70 in the `__init__.py`) or to hardcode the version of the project there.

Another solution could be to install and leave the metadata with the project, another approach would be to delete everything in the dist-info folder except the METADATA file.

You could however roll back to version `3.3.1` which is prior to that breaking change.

edit: I made a change to pyproj a few days after this message, so this is fixed and no longer happens